# Set username and password in VpnNetwork programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app that demands a signed-in VPN connection to access it. The problem I face is that, most of the end-users do not have any knowledge of creating a profile in some VPN, and then to connect to the app.

Is there a way to create a VPN Profile programmatically, and then Connect to it after the creation?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that, in order to access the app you are developing, it has to get signed-in to a **VPN**. If I am right, then you are typically in search of a **Third-party API** like facebook, twitter APIs, through which you should connect to your app. I suggest you to search if any VPN provide such kind of **API service**.